# How do I persist the same random number on multiple function invocations?

Tags: javascript

I've been away from JavaScript for a good while now and I'm trying to bone up again. I'm working on a pretty simple problem, where I want to write a function that randomly generates a number, and then persist the same random number and invoke the function multiple times until I guess the right number. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to generate ONE random number and have it persist through multiple invocations of my guessMyNumber function. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Here's my code so far:

```
function guessMyNumber(n, upperBound) {
  var randomNumber = randInt(upperBound);
  if (n > upperBound) {
    return "Out of bounds! Please try a number between 0 and " + upperBound;
  } else if (n === randomNumber) {
    return "You guessed my number!";
  }
  return "Nope! That wasn't it! The correct guess was: " + randomNumber;
}

function randInt(n) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (n + 1))
}
```

Comment: store it outside of `guessMyNumber`. don't call it again

Comment: https://xkcd.com/221/

Answer (score 0):

```
var randomNumber = "";
function guessMyNumber(n, upperBound) {
  if(randomNumber == ""){ // it means you have not yet generated your number
    randomNumber = randInt(upperBound);
  }
  if (n > upperBound) {
    return "Out of bounds! Please try a number between 0 and " + upperBound;
  } else if (n === randomNumber) {
    return "You guessed my number!";
  }
  return "Nope! That wasn't it! The correct guess was: " + randomNumber;
}

function randInt(n) {
 return Math.floor(Math.random() * (n + 1))
}
```

Comment: ...how? Every time you run it, the randomNumber variable will revert back to "" which means a new number will generate. Is there something I'm fundamentally misunderstanding here? Am I supposed to just repeatedly invoke it over and over such as: 

guessMyNumber(5, 7)
guessMyNumber(5, 7)
guessMyNumber(5, 7)
guessMyNumber(5, 7)

Until i get it right?

Comment: randomNumber is only declared as "" when it is defined. And it is defined only once outside of the function. After the first invocation it will be the same number for every invocation after that. Except if you reload the whole file every time. In that case it will not work since it will be defined all over again.

Comment: In that case you would need to store the number outside of the file, and check every time you invoke it if the number is there.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you can do this, some better than others (depending on your end goal and personal preference)

Another commenter already mentioned moving the variable outside of the function. That works because of how `scope` works in JavaScript.

However, usually this approach is frowned upon due to introducing `global` variables. An alternative is the `IIFE` approach. Something like:

```
let guessMyNumber = (function () {
    var randomNumber;
    return function (n, upperBound) {
        if (upperBound) {
            randomNumber = randInt(upperBound);
        }
        if (n > upperBound) {
            return `Out of bounds! Please try a number between 0 and ${upperBound}`;
        } else if (n === randomNumber) {
            return `You guessed my number!`;
        } else {
            return `Nope, that wasn't it! The correct guess was ${randomNumber}`;
        }
    }
    function randInt(n) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (n + 1))
    }
}());
```

Basically, you've created a `closure` that hides the variable `randomNumber` from the global scope, but allows the value to persist after your first call. I would imagine invoking the function would look something like:

```
guessMyNumber(1, 3);    // "Nope, that wasn't it! The correct guess was 3"
guessMyNumber(2);       // "Nope, that wasn't it! The correct guess was 3"
guessMyNumber(3);       // "You guessed my number!"
```

Passing the `upperBound` again would "reset" the game, allowing you to continue.

A second approach could be returning a function that then is responsible for handling the "guessing" part. The idea is that you would `initialize` the upperBound and then pass your guesses after.  That may look something like:

```
function initGuessMyNumber (upperBound) {
    var randomNumber = randInt(upperBound);
    return function (guess) {
        if (guess > upperBound) {
            return `Out of bounds! Please try a number between 0 and ${upperBound}`;
        } else if (guess === randomNumber) {
            return `You guessed my number!`;
        } else {
            return `Nope, that wasn't it! The correct guess was ${randomNumber}`;
        }
    }
}
```

While very similar to the first approach, the difference is in how you call the function. The sequence may look something like:

```
let guessMyNumberGame = initGuessMyNumber(3);   // Assign the returned function to our variable
guessMyNumberGame(1);   // "Nope, that wasn't it! The correct guess was 3"
guessMyNumberGame(2);   // "Nope, that wasn't it! The correct guess was 3"
guessMyNumberGame(3);   // "You guessed my number!"
```

However, that feels slightly odd in itself. If you were to go with this approach, I would suggest just going full blown `Class` (or Constructor, if you're not in the ES6 game yet) and make it `official`. Something like:

```
class GuessingGame {
    constructor (upperBound) {
        this.upperBound = upperBound;
        this.randomNumber = this.constructor.randInt(upperBound);
    }
    guess (guess) {
        if (guess > this.upperBound) {
            return `Out of bounds! Please try a number between 0 and ${upperBound}`;
        } else if (guess === this.randomNumber) {
            return `You guessed my number!`;
        } else {
            return `Nope, that wasn't it! The correct guess was ${this.randomNumber}`;
        }
    }
    reset (newUpperBound) {
        this.upperBound = newUpperBound;
        this.randomNumber = this.constructor.randInt(newUpperBound);
    }
    static randInt(n) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (n + 1));
    }
}
```

Calling the above would look something like:

```
let game = new GuessingGame(3);
game.guess(1);  // "Nope, that wasn't it! The correct guess was 3"
game.guess(2);  // "Nope, that wasn't it! The correct guess was 3"
game.guess(3);  // "You guessed my number!"
```

If you wanted to play a new game, you could do something like:

```
game.reset(100);
game.guess(40); // "Nope, that wasn't it! The correct guess was 37"
```

And so on. Obviously, this is vastly different from what you asked, but personally it would be the approach I would take if I wanted to maintain `state` for a Guessing Game. Any way, hopefully this was helpful!

Welcome back to the world of JavaScript and Good Luck :)